# How to tackle a mobile which fell into water?

Tags: technology, water

I have a Samsung J7 mobile which fell into water in a drum, how to repair my mobile phone at this situation? I also open next 1 hour but it did not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question is very good; the most important all aspect of recovering an electronic device that has taken a bath, is to remove or disconnect the battery. Supplying power to an immersed circuit causes corrosion and leads to failure. Most phones including phones with non removable batteries like iPhones can still be opened up and have the battery connector unplugged and it should be performed as a matter of urgency. The rest of the tricks should be secondary to this action. Always wise to keep a screwdriver set that fits your phone and a bottle of distilled water hanging around - few bucks off of eBay

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it into a container of rice deep inside and leave it for 2-3 hours.And luckily you have J-7 it has a non removable battery so remove the battery and leave it in sun for 1-2 hours.It will definitely work.